# React-Redux show popup only once everyday

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, react-redux

I have a React application and the state is maintained through Redux store. I want to show a popup message to the user only once everyday when he loads the site for the first time.

The ideal implementation for this would be to use local storage to remember when the last popup was and show popup only when the last popup show date is not today.

I would like to know if there is any react-redux way of doing this and if there are libraries already available for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [quite a few libraries](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/acddc6eda7fe42993c2c6cf61576d11f14709a49/store-persistence.md#persistence-libraries) that can be used to persist your store state (or part of it) to local storage.

Probably the most popular of the bunch is [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).  Using it you could do something like:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux' 
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'

const modalReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_MODAL':
      return {
        ...state,
        display: true,
        lastShown: new Date()
      }
    case 'HIDE_MODAL':
      return {
        ...state,
        display: false
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}

const modalPersistConfig = { key: 'modal', blacklist: ['display'], storage }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  modal: persistReducer(modalPersistConfig, modalReducer)
  // other reducers
})

const store = createStore(reducer)
persistStore(store)
```

Then you can check the date in the store (`store.getState().modal.lastShown`) and dispatch a `SHOW_MODAL` action if it's not today's date.

Comment: I was playing around with redux-localStorage but this looks a lot easy to implement and maintain. I'm gonna try this right away. Thank :)

Comment: I'm sure redux-localstorage would be good for the job too. I haven't actually used either before, so I'd love to hear how you go with it.