# Is there a way to identify if a page(specifically a component) has been visited earlier after login in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react development, I have a home page that will open a modal(something like a pop up asking to accept certain offers), so I've put a call in componentWillMount to a method that fetches data and fills up the modal using data received from API endpoint.

This all works good enough, but if the user is still logged in and comes back to this page the method call to open modal should not be made, how do I handle this? Is there a way to know if a page has been visited earlier after login?

We use [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) module to redirect and load routes, I checked if I can get something from it to recognize if this route has been visited in current session, but it did not help.

We do not have control over server side code so I would prefer solution that involves complete client-side solution?

Comment: Couldn't you set a state flag in a redux store saying that the modal was opened?

Comment: Oh the thing is Modal opens in a loop, that is if I get 5 objects it'll open 5 times, it on the page until all 5 offers are accepted. So flag isn't that helpful.

Comment: But that does mean that you know you have loaded the 5 offers, as they would be available in some store from on that time?

Comment: Yes, the thing is I would prefer a way that tells me if the page has been visited(or component has been viewed) so that I could also write other logic based on it in future. Also I would like to stay away from setting flags. Is there a react (or redux) way to do it?

Comment: But that would be at least a redux way, using a store to set some state that it has been visited before. I don't really see why you want to stay away from that. In `componentWillMount` you can say that it was activated. Where else do you want to save this state (it is a state, as it does change how your application behaves)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate, but you may find something useful in a answer I gave to a similar use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198871/6902543)

Comment: hehe yes that's what I finally went with thanks for the suggestion and your time it's working great, but what I meant was that some method which could manage history in case I have a larger app and might want to check it on all pages(Which off course is not my case still) something generic could help :)

Comment: @MichaelPeyper yes that's similar but I am not interested in storing the whole state just a minor flag that I should not have managed instead react-reddux should've managed.

Comment: @TGW That example only persisted a small part of the state for tracking if the modal had been shown that day, nothing else.  But I realise I have misunderstood your requirement as you want the modal to be suppressed if it has already been shown in that session, not that day, right?

Comment: I guess you could theoretically create a higher order function, that integrates some state management with any given components, that would enable an action on a predefined action on your part (ie: `onLoad` where the `onLoad` function is called by the higher order function `componentWillMount` implementation based on a given store/state key)

Comment: @MichaelPeyper not actually the modal but the page on which the modal was shown, if that page is visited even thought the modal is not shown then in that whole session the modal should not show up no matter if modal was showed for first time. The only thing that matters is the page on which modal is shown

Comment: @TGW would [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eavd7kf9/7/) give you any assistance? In the [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/eavd7kf9/8/) the second class doesn't load it's data, so I believe that is something you want to do

Comment: Are you using `redux-thunk` when fetching the data?  If so, can you use the presence of the data to modify the behaviour, e.g.  (sorry for inline code) `const showOffers = () => (dispatch, getState) => { if (!getState().offers) { fetchOffers().then((offers) => { dispatch(setOffers(offers)); dispatch(showOfferModal()); } }`

Comment: @TGW Anything that you found helpful then afterwards?

Comment: Apologies for late reply, I ended up using local storage for now. Will try thunk